# On-premise Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api

I have read many articles about Exchange hybrid mode, Microsoft Graph, EWS, but it is not clear:
Is it possible in a completely offline configuration (on premise AD, Exchange 2016) to access/edit users' mailboxes, calendars?
If yes. In what way? EWS? Ms Graph?
So without O365.
Is there a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it possible in a completely offline configuration (on premise AD, Exchange 2016) to access/edit users' mailboxes, calendars?

So your just talking about regular exchange ? yes EWS will work for that like it has since Exchange 2007 I would start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220499(v=exchg.80)

Comment: Thank for your answer.  EWS is a good old tool. Do you think it will last long. Right now I want to develop an application for a client who doesn't want to move to the cloud.
Is there any other more modern tool in on-premise environment to access exchange operations?

Comment: If they are a current Exchange OnPrem customer with no hybrid they using EWS is your best option. If they are going to stay an OnPrem customer EWS is supported on all current version of OnPrem Exchange (can't say about future OnPrem version if they even eventuate). That said building a greenfield EWS application isn't going to be future proof but should be good for few years in a customer environment that doesn't change a lot.